# observable update passing multiple args

Tags: java, observable

I'm building a program that has the following classes:

**DataModel** - Extends Observable and is storing the strings for the labels in our GUi 

**Display** - implements Observer and has our update method & labels

When the controller makes a change to the String statusText in DataModel I call setChanged() & notifyObservers(this.statusText) which then calls update(Observable o, Object arg) in the Display class.

My question is when I have multiple strings for different labels how should I proceed? My first thought is to put all the strings into a list and then the update method looks like the following (is this too much coupling?):

```
    if (arg != null && arg instanceof String[]) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String[] strings = (String[]) arg;
                status.setText(strings[0]);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider refactoring the design a little. instead of **DataModel** simply pushing strings, create another type that represents the state of the model that might be relevant to downstream views, like:

```
class State {
    public String lastModifiedBy;
    public String lastModifiedAt;
}
```

...then have **DataModel** expose a method that returns an `Observable<State>` that views can subscribe to, like:

```
dataModel.bind().subscribe(
    state -> {
        status.setText(state.lastModifiedBy)

        someOtherTextView.setText(state. lastModifiedAt)
    },
    error -> {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), error)
    }
)
```

coming up with the "right" abstraction will take some thought, but introducing that intermediary type between the views and the model gives you some ability to evolve them independent of one another.

read up on the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) design pattern, if you haven't already.

Comment: similar to a state machine in that the different viewModels represent the state of the label text in the view. Then the curentState is changed instead of the actual value and when the currentState changes it passes to the update?

Comment: how many ViewModels you have is up to you - you can have one per page/screen, one per view, etc. whatever makes sense to you as the designer. as the model is updated, it should emit new instances of the class(es) that describe state, which will trigger `onNext` of any subscribed observers, and at which point the views can then update themselves to reflect any relevant change in state.